# Wrapping pointer this into a shared_ptr

Tags: c++, stl, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

In the following example I tried to wrap `this` pointer into an `std::shared_ptr` (for instance for sending to a composite object as a parent pointer).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass() { std::shared_ptr<MyClass> ptr(this); std::cout << (long long)ptr.get() << std::endl; }
    ~MyClass() { std::cout << (long long)this << "del" << std::endl; }
    int field;
};

int main() {
    MyClass* instance = new MyClass;
    std::cout << (long long)instance << "assign" << std::endl;
    instance->field = 5;
    delete instance;
    return 0;
}
```

The code issues the following output

> 140736965201520 
>   140736965201520del 
>   140736965201520assign 
>   140736965201520del

According to the output, I can suppose, that the object was deleted twice. Furthermore, it was deleted after the `shared_ptr` was deleted (in the constructor).

Any suggestions on how to wrap the `this` into a `shared_ptr` and pass to others?

Comment: See [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this)

Comment: The flag duplicate isn't correct. I asked about using it from the constructor. But as you can see in the post it says, that the method isn't correct when you try to get it from the constructor